# Google Cloud Kubernetes with 3 Micro Instances (Free tier) - Not useable AT ALL?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I'm using google cloud with the free tier and the free credits, and I wanted to try out kubernetes.

I create node pool of 3 f1-micro instances (only f1-micro instances are eligible for free tier). It seems each one should end up with 240mb of memory.

However, I tried to create a simple deployment with a pod requesting 100Mi of memory, and I'm getting an Insufficient Memory errors.

Does that mean google cloud Kubernetes isn't really usable with the free tier, hence it's not free at all?
Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

For each of the nodes run `kubectl describe nodename`  which will show lot of details about the node and look for `Allocatable` and `Allocated resources`. You may notice that almost all the memory is used, and f1-micro is limited to an average of 0.2 CPU which has been exceeded just by the k8s system pods.

You can try editing the deployment of system pods such as CoreDNS and reduce the requests of the pods

Comment: yeah I know - that is exactly my point. Instead of 600mb more than half of it is reserved by google cloud (according to docs as well), and then the left is almost completely used by kubernetes services/pods. Is there anything I can do about it though? Or is GKE not really free?

Comment: You can try editing the deployment of system pods such as CoreDNS and reduce the requests of the pods.